# Setting a header in CakePHP (MVC)

Tags: cakephp, paypal, header

I'm trying to integrate PayPal's IPN code into CakePHP 3.

```
namespace App\Controller;
use PayPal\Api\PaypalIPN;

class IpnController extends AppController
{

public function index()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $ipn = new PayPalIPN();
    // Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
    $ipn->useSandbox();
    $verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
    if ($verified) {
        /*
         * Process IPN
         * A list of variables is available here:
         * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
         */
    }
    // Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  }

}
```

This is failing to validate on PayPal's end and I'm suspecting it has to do with setting the headers in the controller view.

Is there a way to set the header properly in CakePHP's controller.

I had this code running stand alone (in just a php file) and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should not output any data in your controller action - that means you should not use `echo`, `header()` or any function or construct that would return anything to browser. If you do, you will encounter a "headers already sent" error.

If you want to set headers, you should use `withHeader()` or `withAddedHeader()` methods of `Cake\Http\Response`.

For status codes, you also have `withStatus()` method:

```
$response = $this->response;
$response = $response->withStatus(200,"OK");
return $response; // returning response will stop controller from rendering a view.
```

More about setting headers can be found in docs:

[Setting response headers in CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-headers)

[Cake\Http\Response::withStatus()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Http.Client.Response.html#_withStatus)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not very Cakish, but actually one can send headers this way - it just have to be followed by `die;` or `exit;` to prevent app from further response processing.

Anyway, for sure your problem is not associated with headers. IPN seems to doesn't work properly with Paypal Sandbox. Maybe you should try it other way with ApiContext class?